# how can I get the last value for each key in a set of postgres hstore records?

Tags: postgresql, hstore, windowing

I have a table of sensor readings as postgres `hstore key-value pairs`.
Each record has a timestamp at 1 sec intervals.
Not all sensors record every second.

The table is essentially:

```
create table readings (
    timer timestamp primary key,
    readings hstore
);
```

the hstore comprises (<sensor_id> ) key/value pairs for readings taken at the time specified in the timestamp.

eg:  "67" "-45.67436", "68" "176.5424" could be key/value pairs representing latitude & longitude, with a timestamp in the timer column.

There would be several lat/lon hstore pairs in a given minute, the query I want would return the last one in the timeseries for that minute (for each key).

I want to retrieve the latest value for each sensor in the hstore at 1 minute intervals.

Essentially:
Get the set of timestamps & hstores for that minute.
Get the keys from that set.
Get the value for that key from the key-value pair with the latest timestamp in the set
Return the 1 min timestamp & resulting hstore
Repeat for the next minute

I'm happy with a pl/pgsql function if that is the best approach.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review the help section [ask].  In particular post your table definitions (ddl) and sample date, as text - **no images**, and the expected results of that data. Additionally show what query you have tried and indicate specifically what problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

for

> "the query I want would return the last one in the timeseries for that
> minute (for each key)"

you can use windows function, also I'm guessing you have different sensors

```
select * from 
( 
   select * , row_number() over (partition by sensorid, to_char(timer, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM') order by timer desc) rn
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with t(t, h) as (values
    ('2000-01-01 01:01:01'::timestamp, 'a=>1,b=>2'::hstore),
    ('2000-01-01 01:01:02', 'a=>3'),
    ('2000-01-01 01:02:03', 'b=>4'),
    ('2000-01-01 01:02:05', 'a=>2,b=>3'))
select
    date_trunc('minute', t),
    jsonb_object_agg(k, v order by t)
from t, each(h) as h(k,v)
group by date_trunc('minute', t);

┌─────────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│     date_trunc      │   jsonb_object_agg   │
├─────────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ 2000-01-01 01:01:00 │ {"a": "3", "b": "2"} │
│ 2000-01-01 01:02:00 │ {"a": "2", "b": "3"} │
└─────────────────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=abf5f5c8c64016ff36fed4c11b261fb8)